# Compare different columns from different sheets and add missing values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet where I would like to compare Column A from different sheets "RawData" and "ForTraining" to perform following tasks

Link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19Dqr6ZCq5dO_WO32_xcZV4E5QfJjExe8fgpvd4zj7bE/edit#gid=0

1, Add an entire row to ForTraining Sheet if there is a new entry in RawData for example in RawData, Column A has a new entry Id 11, the entire row must be copied to ForTraining Sheet.

2, After comparing if ForTraining sheet has any Ids that is not present in RawData, the entire column should be deleted from ForTraining Sheet.

Example: In the provided sheet,

In Raw Data Id 5 and 6 were removed, the same has to be removed from ForTraining Sheet.

So far I've tried the following code but this is not removing the missing items from Raw data and it is not updating the new entry correctly

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceData = sheet.getSheetByName('RawData');
  var lastRowSource = (sourceData.getRange("A2").getDataRegion().getLastRow()) - 1;
  var sourceValues = sourceData.getRange(2,1,lastRowSource,1).getValues().filter(String)
  var targetData = sheet.getSheetByName('ForTraining');
  var lastRowTarget = (targetData.getRange("A2").getDataRegion().getLastRow()) - 1;
  var targetValues = targetData.getRange(2,1,lastRowTarget,1).getValues().filter(String)
  var targetRange =  targetData.getRange(2,1,lastRowTarget,1);

  var diff = targetValues.showDif(sourceValues)
  targetRange.clearContent();
  targetValues = (diff && diff.length) ? targetValues.concat(diff) : targetValues;
  targetData.getRange(2, 1, targetValues.length, targetValues[0].length).setValues(targetValues)
 }

Array.prototype.showDif = function (array) {
    let that = this;
    return array.filter(function (r) {
        return !that.some(function (x) {
            return r.join() === x.join();
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function UpdateSheet() {
  var toObj = v => v.reduce((o, r) => (o[r[0]] = r, o), {});
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName('RawData');
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName('ForTraining');
  var srcValues = srcSheet.getRange(2, 1, srcSheet.getLastRow() - 1, srcSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var srcObj = toObj(srcValues);
  var dstRange = dstSheet.getRange(2, 1, dstSheet.getLastRow() - 1, dstSheet.getLastColumn());
  var dstValues = dstRange.getValues();
  var dstObj = toObj(dstValues);
  var values = [...dstValues.filter(r => srcObj[r[0]]), ...srcValues.filter(r => !dstObj[r[0]])];
  if (values.length == 0) return;
  dstRange.clearContent().offset(0, 0, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- In your showing script, `sourceValues` is one column. By this, `diff` is one column. From your question, when you want to use all columns by filtering 1st column when all values are used in the script, this might be a simple script. So, I proposed the above sample script.

#### Note:

- I tested this script using your provided sample Spreadsheet. If you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Thank you so much, this looks really simple and it is quite hard for me to understand as I'm new to the coding. As you made my life easier, I would like to ask you one more thing. What if  I wanted to know the count of names that were removed and added.

Comment: @Raghul Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `I would like to ask you one more thing. What if I wanted to know the count of names that were removed and added.`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. Can I ask you the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to try to understand your new question. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your various questions soon.

Comment: Not a problem, lets say in RawData Sheet Two New entries are added and one old entry is removed, to the the code you've provided I added this line for a pop up alert

'var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Data Updated", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(result);'

I've provided the message "Data Updated" in Pop up alert, instead of this it can say, Data updated - 2 New entries were added and 1 old Entry was removed. I hope this is clear, thanks in advance )

Comment: @Raghul Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your new question. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. But, I would like to try to understand your new question. When I could correctly understand your new question, I would like to think of a solution. When you can give me time to understand your new question. I'm glad. Can you give me time to do it?

Comment: @Raghul Although I could understand your 1st question, I cannot still understand your new question. I think that this is due to my very poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my very poor English skill again. I have to study English more.